# Qual a origem da expressão «colegas são as putas»?

Tags: expressões, origem-histórica, expressões-idiomáticas

Hoje, ao falar com umas amigas advogadas num chat deparei-me com elas a dizerem que os advogados entre si tratam-se por colegas:

> O colega não sabe que o código do trabalho mudou em 2016?

E eu muito prontamente disse:

> Mas vocês não sabem que colegas são as putas?

Esta expressão usa-se muito quando «colegas» é usado no sentido mais formal. No Brasil é informal tratar as pessoas por você, mas em Portugal é bem formal. A frase acima de forma informal seria:

> Amigo, tu não sabes que o código do trabalho mudou em 2016?

E então fiquei a pensar... Qual será a origem dessa expressão?

Eu sei que a expressão é bastante usada no exercito para dar a ideia que entre soldados não pode haver cerimonias, que têm de ser camaradas, ou amigos e nunca «colegas»:

> Soldado - pedi a um Colega para me guardar a arma.
>
> Sargento - Colega? Ó sua besta, não sabe que colegas são as putas?

Comment: Colega em pt-BR é alguém com quem se convive no trabalho ou escola "eles são colegas de trabalho" , "elas são colegas de classe" (da mesma sala de aula).

Comment: @AndréLyra aqui também são colegas. Mas é costume usar-se a expressão quando se usa "colega" com sentido que eu disse acima de "distanciação". Vou tentar clarificar isso.

Comment: @AndréLyra veja se entende o meu ponto agora, editei a pergunta.

Comment: Nunca ouvi essa expressão no Brasil.  Acredito que seja exclusiva do linguajar lusitano.

Comment: @Centaurus acredito que sim. Nem sei se é usada em todo país, aqui no norte é comumente usada quando se trata alguém por colega quando não se está a vontade com a pessoa. Para quebrar o gelo em alguma situação informal.

Comment: Acho que respondeu na sua última frase, julgo que serviu exatamente para referir no meio militar, que entre os membros das forças armadas, não há uma relação colegial, mas de camaradagem. Logo, julgo que a origem é a do meio militar.

Comment: Colega com outro sentido que conheço é com alguns gays que que chamam uns (umas?) aos outros de "Coleeeegaaaa!"

Answer (score 3):

Eu sou lisboeta e nunca ouvi a expressão. Contudo a expressão não deve ser entendida como universal tal como outra similar como *"você é estrebaria"*. Como sabemos em Português existe uma ampla forma de tratamentos tão grande que a sua hierarquia varia muito regionalmente e nos meios socio-profissionais. *Colega* usa-se como pronome pessoal sujeito de forma semi-formal, mais formal que *você* e denota reconhecimento de mesmo nível em termo sociais com a pessoa com quem se fala, dai o sufixo "*co-*". O mesmo acontece em Alemão. Entre engenheiros, médicos, advogados e por ai fora. Depois há claro o uso mais comum como os colegas da escola da universidade, mas aqui não é usado como "pronome pessoal sujeito" mas como substantivo. Na zona das Beiras usa-se *colega* como sinónimo de amigo, já que *amigo / amiga* tem ai ainda o significado medieval de namorado. Para norte do Mondego o pronome pessoal sujeito "*você*" só muito tardiamente entrou em uso e era tido como "afectação" citadina, modernices das gentes das cidades que vinham para os campos todos limpinhos e janota se não mesmo altivez. Daí que na Beira Baixa haja a curiosa expressão "*Você é estrebaria!*". Vale a pena conferir esta expressão no [ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-expressao-voce-e-estrebaria/32198)

Answer (score 0):

Entendi que queres realmente saber o significado da expressão *colegas são as putas*.
Essa é uma expressão utilizada em Portugal (nunca ouvi no Brasil) e dá o entender que a pessoa está pedindo mais respeito na forma de tratamento. Ao chamar alguém de *colega*, pode estar vinculando as pessoas no mesmo nível hierárquico, algo não aceito pelo ouvinte.

Fontes: [1](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/significado/colegas+s%E3o+as+putas/25298/) e [2](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/colegas+s%E3o+as+putas/)

Comment: Por acaso eu tenho a ideia que é precisamente o contrário. No exercito temos de ser companheiros, amigos, porque precisamos uns dos outros e não somente colegas. Mas o que eu queria saber é a origem da expressão.

Comment: como a origem realmente deve ser lusitana, não saberia dizer. Mas lendo os textos relacionados, continuo pensando que é uma forma de solicitação de respeito, inclusive vários exemplos são militares com hierarquias diferentes.

Comment: @JorgeB. Verdade. "Jornalistas são camaradas e tratam-se sempre por tu. Colegas são as putas." (http://jugular.blogs.sapo.pt/1230020.html)

Comment: apenas a distinção que se faz entre colegas e amigos.